# What's the best way of removing whitespace from the top of my web part page?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer

Apologies for the simplicity of this one, I've tried lots of searches online but not found a solution.

All I want to do is remove the whitespace above "My page title" so that the title sits at the top of the screen - quite a lot of real estate is unecessarily wasted currently.

I've tried editing the code in SharePoint designer but large portions of it are uneditable, I'd also rather there was a GUI solution if possible.

[image: Image of SharePoint homepage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all click edit page and check if your space contains empty html elements (*p* of *div*) and delete it.
If it is a css styles problem, you can click html->edit source in the ribbon, and add correct styles to your page.

Comment: Thanks - this answer helped me the most. By editing the html source I was able to remove the paragraph styling which had all the extra padding on it. This means I've had to manually re-apply styling to that portion of the screen - but it aligns to the top now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is caused by top and bottom margin of the element which repersents your page title. You can use tools like IE developer toolbar (IE) or Firebug (Firefox) to locate corresponding CSS styles and modify or override it.

Answer (score 0):

That whitespace is actually the 2nd level of Tabs from the Ribbon and cannot be removed without consequences. If you still feel like doing so, you need to change CSS styles for

## s4-ribbonrow and .s4-ribboncont

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "View"

   2. Click on "Fit to Window"
   3. Drag the drawing up to the top of the white space with your mouse

Comment: You can add some screenshots or reference to support your answer